# Linq Expression tree preprocessing. Debugger issue

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, debugging, reflection

I read article how EntityFramework translates expressions to SQL queries. Interesting part was how EF preprocess expression tree to exclude closures, and local properties from tree and replace them with actual value. Here is my code. I was trying to figure out when and in what cases local properties are evaluates. But i can't catch this moment with debugger. But i see some state changes.

```
    private bool _called1;
    private bool _called2;
    protected bool Noob1 {
        get {
            Debugger.Break();  // never works
            _called1 = true;  // changes to true sometimes
            return true;
        }
    }

    public bool Noob2 {
        get {
            Debugger.Break();  // never works
            _called2 = true; // changes to true sometimes
            return false;
        }
    }
    public ActionResult Index() {
        var dn = new ApplicationDbContext();
        var q1 = dn.Heros.Where(h => h.IsNoob == Noob1);
        dn.Heros.Where(h => h.IsNoob == Noob2);

        var result = this.GetType().GetMethod("About").Invoke(this, null); // to test breakpoint inside About action. call it using reflection
        return Content(String.Format("c1={0}; c2={1}", _called1, _called2));
    }

    public ActionResult About()
    {
        // if i place breakpoint here is fires, so no problem with debugger and invoking through reflection
        ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";

        return View();
    }
```

Every time I run this code _called1 or _called2 it true. Sometimes they are both true. But breakpoints didn't work inside my properties. How this is possible? Why _called1 and _called2 change their values so unpredictable? How to see thead callstack when EF preprocess my expression tree?

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Hero> Heros { get; set; }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

P.S.
After i finished writing this question I understand what i write my Heros set to wrong DbContext. But i don't think that this can cause the problem.

Comment: Are you sure that the query is even processed? EF uses lazy loading, so queries are executed only when they are needed. Add a `.ToList()` or similar methods to the query to force it to execute.

Comment: @NicoSchertler EF do not translate is to sql in my code. But it must resolve Noob1 & Noob2 propetries to Constant Expressions
I even see that _called1 and _called2 variables changes.

Comment: @NicoSchertler you were right. When i add `.ToList()` breakpoints fires.

But i found out another strange things. If i change my `Noob1 and Noob2` to protected then _called1 and _called2 are both false.

If i change order of `dn.Heros.Where(h => h.IsNoob == Noob2);
            dn.Heros.Where(h => h.IsNoob == Noob1)` then they are both true.

Comment: When you call Where certainly nothing is evaluated yet. You must evaluate the query to trigger anything. If you do that by hovering the mouse over some expression this uses the Visual Studio expression evaluator. Maybe the debugger (which is already attached) does not break under these circumstances. The evaluator will not trigger manual breakpoints either. What does it matter? Just use ToList.